# Disable Computer Monitoring Programs in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello Developers,
                 I Want to disable all computer Monitoring programs like **TeamViewer** when my winform application runs.I want to prevent my application tracking so i need this.Right now for temporary solution i close all the applications & it's processes when my application run.But i want to close only Monitoring programs(e.g. **TeamViewer**) not all programs.So is any idea to disable these types of programs.?? My code is as following.Thanks in Advance.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Process myApplicationProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        if (allProcesses.Count() > 1)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Ohter Applications are running\r\nYou must need to close all", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (p.Id != myApplicationProcess.Id)
                        p.CloseMainWindow();
                }
                Application.Run(new frmBrowser());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Requests like this are usually for nefarious purposes, and the community generally does not want to assist with them. Perhaps if you explain why it is important to want to disable these other programs, and what your program is for, you will get more assistance.

Comment: whats wrong with this.?? I just want to prevent my application that no one user can access my application using TeamViewer or any other Remote Desktop Program.There is no nefarious purpose of my app.

Comment: Imposing your application's control over a user's computer is usually bad. It is not your computer to be creating that restriction on. If you are trying to ensure license compliance, that is a different topic entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Working in a security field I can just recommend you to leave this idea alone.

There are way too many problems with your approach:

- It requires administrative permissions
- Not all application can be killed that easily
- You have to *black-list* application, meaning you have to always update your list
- Users will get upset, specifically in a corporate world, admins will simply ban your application

You just don't do this. There is no secure way to protect your application from being logged in the environment that you don't have control of.

Comment: Will be interested to know what is incorrect in this answer or how can I improve this

Comment: whats wrong with this.?? I just want to prevent my application that no one user can access my application using TeamViewer or any other Remote Desktop Program.There is no nefarious purpose of my app.

Comment: I can see you wanting that, this is just an answer and someone downvoted it. I was curious what is incorrect in it. I think you cannot do this unless you have full control over the destination system. Do you have such control? BTW I am the one who gave you +1 :). I think it's a good question, and perhaps fortunately (sic!) the answer is "no, you cannot do this".

Comment: Suppose i already connected with other user with Remote Desktop program for some work.so he/she can do all things on my system.now suppose after complete that work i forget to close remote program and i start my winform application then he can track my application.i want to prevent it.so i think to disable these type of programs on my application startup.I hope u understand my requirement.